# Dual boot Windows 7 and windows 8 not booting

Tags: windows-8

i have windows 7 installed on one drive which was my main drive. Last week i bought windows 8 and installed it on a secondry drive which is completly different to my windows 7. i have removed my windows 7 drive as i wont be using it and only one windows 8 problem is that the boot partition for windows 8 is on the original drive and it wont allow me to boot after removing drive

Comment: You will have to use the Windows Installer put the boot partition on the new drive.

Comment: Windows installs its bootloader on the first physical hard drive. You have to install it on the second drive too. Running Win8 installer and choosing the "Repair" option should fix it without any data loss.